# Scraping of Web Page Tables using Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do a web scraping of table and its content from [an Apple wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Apple_Inc._products). I am using Beautiful Soup to extract the data. I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
appleurl="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Apple_Inc._products"
import requests
import pandas as pad
import lxml.html as html
_content = requests.get(appleurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(_content.content)
_table = soup.findChildren('table')
rows = _table[0].findChildren(['th','tr'])
for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        value = cell.string
        print ("The value in this cell is %s"% value)
```

I am having the following values:

```
The value in this cell is 1976
The value in this cell is April 11
The value in this cell is Apple I
The value in this cell is Apple I
The value in this cell is September 1, 1977

The value in this cell is 1977
The value in this cell is April 1
The value in this cell is Apple II
The value in this cell is Apple II
The value in this cell is June 1, 1979

The value in this cell is 1978
The value in this cell is June 1
The value in this cell is Disk II
The value in this cell is Drives
The value in this cell is May 1, 1984

The value in this cell is 1979
The value in this cell is June 1
The value in this cell is Apple II Plus
The value in this cell is Apple II series
The value in this cell is December 1, 1982

The value in this cell is None
The value in this cell is None
The value in this cell is None
The value in this cell is Bell & Howell Disk II
The value in this cell is None
The value in this cell is Apple SilenType
The value in this cell is Printers
The value in this cell is October 1, 1982
```

The problem is that for the year `1979` the number of models are multiple which is not being extracted in my case. I need all the models for the year `1979`. The code I have can extracting perfectly fine if there is a single row for each year. What shall I do if there are multiple rows for a single year as in the first table of the link I provided.
The values I need is Year, Release Date, Model. The other two columns can be eliminated.
I will really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can simply use pandas to do that.use `pad.read_html()`

```
import pandas as pad

df=pad.read_html('https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Apple_Inc._products')[0]
print(pd.concat([df['Year'],df['Release Date'],df['Model']], axis=1, sort=False))
```

**Output**:

```
 Year Release Date                  Model
0  1976     April 11                Apple I
1  1977      April 1               Apple II
2  1978       June 1                Disk II
3  1979       June 1          Apple II Plus
4  1979       June 1      Apple II EuroPlus
5  1979       June 1        Apple II J-Plus
6  1979       June 1          Bell & Howell
7  1979       June 1  Bell & Howell Disk II
8  1979       June 1        Apple SilenType
```

---

**Update** for all **tables**.

```
import pandas as pad

dfs=pad.read_html('https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Apple_Inc._products')
for df in dfs:
   print(pd.concat([df['Year'],df['Release Date'],df['Model']], axis=1, sort=False))
```

---

If you would like to do it in single dataframe then use this code.

```
import pandas as pad

dfs=pad.read_html('https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Apple_Inc._products')
dffinal=pd.DataFrame()
for df in dfs:
   df1=pd.concat([df['Year'],df['Release Date'],df['Model']], axis=1, sort=False)
   dffinal = dffinal.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

print(dffinal)
```

**Output**:

```
  Year  Release Date                                              Model
0    1976      April 11                                            Apple I
1    1977       April 1                                           Apple II
2    1978        June 1                                            Disk II
3    1979        June 1                                      Apple II Plus
4    1979        June 1                                  Apple II EuroPlus
5    1979        June 1                                    Apple II J-Plus
6    1979        June 1                                      Bell & Howell
7    1979        June 1                              Bell & Howell Disk II
8    1979        June 1                                    Apple SilenType
9    1980   September 1                                          Apple III
10   1980   September 1                           Modem IIB (Novation CAT)
11   1980   September 1                       Printer IIA (Centronics 779)
12   1980   September 1                                        Monitor III
13   1980   September 1                   Monitor II (various third party)
14   1980   September 1                                           Disk III
15   1981   September 1                                      Apple ProFile
16   1981    December 1                               Apple III Revised[1]
17   1982     October 1                           Apple Dot Matrix Printer
18   1982     October 1                          Apple Daisy Wheel Printer
19   1983     January 1                                          Apple IIe
20   1983     January 1                                      Apple Lisa[2]
21   1983    December 1                                     Apple III Plus
22   1983    December 1                                  Apple ImageWriter
23   1984     January 1                                       Apple Lisa 2
24   1984    January 24                                   Macintosh (128K)
25   1984    January 24               Macintosh External Disk Drive (400K)
26   1984    January 24                                    Apple Modem 300
27   1984    January 24                                   Apple Modem 1200
28   1984       April 1                                          Apple IIc
29   1984       April 1                               Apple Scribe Printer
..    ...           ...                                                ...
606  2019      March 18                                iPad Mini (5th gen)
607  2019      March 19   iMac with Retina 4K display (21.5") (Early 2019)
608  2019      March 19     iMac with Retina 5K display (27") (Early 2019)
609  2019      March 20                                  AirPods (2nd gen)
610  2019        May 21  MacBook Pro with Touch Bar (4th gen) (13") (Mi...
611  2019        May 21  MacBook Pro with Touch Bar (4th gen) (15") (Mi...
612  2019        May 28                               iPod Touch (7th gen)
613  2019        July 9                           MacBook Air (13") (2019)
614  2019        July 9  Macbook Pro with Touch Bar (4th gen) (13") (Mi...
615  2019  September 20                               Apple Watch Series 5
616  2019  September 20                        Apple Watch Hermès Series 5
617  2019  September 20                          Apple Watch Nike Series 5
618  2019  September 20                       Apple Watch Edition Series 5
619  2019  September 20                                  iPhone 8 (128 GB)
620  2019  September 20                             iPhone 8 Plus (128 GB)
621  2019  September 20                                          iPhone 11
622  2019  September 20                                      iPhone 11 Pro
623  2019  September 20                                  iPhone 11 Pro Max
624  2019  September 25                                        iPad (2019)
625  2019    October 30                                        AirPods Pro
626  2019   November 13                   MacBook Pro with Touch Bar (16")
627  2019   December 10                                Mac Pro (Late 2019)
628  2019   December 10                                    Pro Display XDR
629  2020      March 18                                                NaN
630  2020      March 18                           iPad Pro (11") (2nd gen)
631  2020      March 18                         iPad Pro (12.9") (4th gen)
632  2020      March 18                        Magic Keyboard for iPad Pro
633  2020      March 18                           MacBook Air (Early 2020)
634  2020      April 24                                iPhone SE (2nd gen)
635  2020         May 4         MacBook Pro with Magic Keyboard (Mid 2020)

[636 rows x 3 columns]
```